# how to add the animation in iphone application using open GL or coreGrapics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, graphics, opengl-es

i am working with a customer feedback application here i am planing to add some animations like on click of next question one cloud should come n drop the questions or some thing like that, can i do that using core graphics or should i use openGL? can any one give me some sample codes or tutorial links?

Comment: If your a member of the iPhone Developer Program you should have access to sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say stay with CoreAnimation as long as you can and only use OpenGL if really need to. Most things are easily doable with CA, and you get lots of features for free (smooth animations, fading, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CAKeyFrameAnimation. You will easily find some sample of this. Try google my friend.